# Is Hurricane Sandy Allah's punishment for US?

Tags: allah, punishment, disasters

In the Quran, Allah has used natural disasters as a way of punishing those who have acted against his will (such as the people of Lut whom he destroyed for being homosexuals).

Is the hurricane Allah sent an example of his displeasure with the US? Their refusal to embrace Islam, their violence towards muslims and refusal to help remove the Alawite tyrants in Syria?

Are there anything else in islam which could back this up?

Comment: **<closed>** It is difficult to understand what you're expecting for an answer here. Discerning God's intentions inre a particular country and a particular natural disaster, as your question appears, hardly seems something that we (the site) can establish with reliable evidence, and as such is out of scope.

Comment: http://tanzil.net/#42:30

Comment: @Ahmadi again, quoting "it is for what your hands have earned" forces you to look also at the natural disasters affecting Muslim peoples.

Comment: I don't know it is punishment from Allah or not, Allah knows best. But what I know is that we Muslims are going through worse time of our history. Instead of doing progress and start learning from our mistakes we waste our time in praying and wishing destruction of west. The site and the technology you are using to ask this question is developed by West (especially Americans), what a pity. I pray to Allah to show us better path where we can learn, progress and make our life better in this world and hereafter.

Comment: +1 for the views this question has generated. 2 days and already 355, great for a beta site... جزاك اللهُ

Comment: @MarcGravell yes Muslims have sin too and Muslims receive punishments too. http://tanzil.net/#49:14 and http://tanzil.net/#12:106

Comment: [Boobquake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boobquake) was an experiment which tested whether women dressed immodestly increased the likelihood of earthquakes, as claimed by Kazem Seddiqi. The conclusion of the experiment was that it did not.

Comment: In the Qur'an, it has been mentioned that certain nations had been destroyed by Allah. This was due to the fact that they had demanded miracles from their prophet, their prophet had demonstrated miracles and yet, those nations had chosen to disbelieve. Allah allows one to continue in disbelief as long as concrete proof has not been provided. Once it has been, then disbelief is no longer an option. In the case of the US, indeed any nation today, there are no more prophets to demonstrate miracles, therefore divine destruction as punishment would not fit in with Allah's rules regarding this.

Comment: related [Does God cause natural disasters?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2150/does-god-cause-natural-disasters) and one line answer http://quran.com/42/30

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go to the pages of holy Qur'an, As an example of storm **([Maybe a hurricane](http://www.free-islamic-course.org/NaturalDisasterorDivinePunishment.html#Layer22))**, you'll find this:

> #### [Surah Al-Ahqaf (Ayaah 21 - 25):](http://quran.com/46/21-25)
>
> And mention, [O Muhammad], the brother of 'Aad, when he warned his people in the [region of] al-Ahqaf - and warners had already passed on before him and after him - [saying], "Do not worship except Allah . Indeed, I fear for you the punishment of a terrible day."
>
> They said, "Have you come to delude us away from our gods? Then bring us what you promise us, if you should be of the truthful."
>
> He said, "Knowledge [of its time] is only with Allah , and I convey to you that with which I was sent; but I see you [to be] a people behaving ignorantly."
>
> And when they saw it as a cloud approaching their valleys, they said, "This is a cloud bringing us rain!" Rather, it is that for which you were impatient: a wind, within it a painful punishment,
>
> Destroying everything by command of its Lord. And they became so that nothing was seen [of them] except their dwellings. Thus do We recompense the criminal people.

The 'Aad are actually the people of Prophet Hud (pbuh). They had disbelieved in Allah and had suffered the punishment. Taking this incident as an example, Allah has warned the people of Muhammad (pbuh) against disbelief in:

> #### [Surah Al-Qamar (Ayaah 18 - 22):](http://quran.com/54/18-22)
>
> 'Aad denied; and how [severe] were My punishment and warning.
>
> Indeed, We sent upon them a screaming wind on a day of continuous misfortune,
>
> Extracting the people as if they were trunks of palm trees uprooted.
>
> And how [severe] were My punishment and warning.
>
> And We have certainly made the Qur'an easy for remembrance, so is there any who will remember?

In light of these Ayaah, you can draw a conclusion that Allah brings disasters to punish the disbelievers.

But if you look at another Ayah, you'll realise that punishment may not be the only motive.

> #### [Surah Al-A'raf (Ayah 94):](http://quran.com/7/94)
>
> And We sent to no city a prophet [who was denied] except that We seized its people with poverty and hardship that they might humble themselves [to Allah].

Apart from the punishment to the disbelievers, Allah also imposes these disasters as a test to believers. Making the believers humble before Allah is also another motive.

As for the Hurricane Sandy, it is not good to say Allah sent this as a punishment to the U.S because there is nothing to confirm it, unlike the calamities over the people of Prophet Hud (pbuh) which were confirmed by The Holy Qur'an. Though owing to the coincidences, you may believe that it is a punishment, and though there are many Ayaah in the Holy Qur'an which state generally that Allah may bring calamities as a punishment, we still have no knowledge of Allah's motive. So, claiming that this was a punishment or expressing it to others or asking questions such as this one (in open) will only spread unpleasant arguments and hatred among people.

#### ۚ  وَاللَّهُ عَلِيمٌ حَكِيمٌ (And Allah is the All-Knower, the Wise)

#### جزاك اللهُ

Answer (score 8):

The hurricane on the east coast is the result of well understood weather conditions that are endemic to that region due to equally understood geographic, coastal and atmospheric conditions. The infrastructure impact, while significant, has resulted in remarkably few deaths, and is mainly inconvenient. High population density contributes to the number of people affected.

Contrast, however:

```
Death Toll   Event                    Location      Date
280,000      Indonesian Tsunami       Indonesia     December 2004
110,000      Ashgabat earthquake      Turkmenistan  October 1948
79,000       Kashmir earthquake       Pakistan      October 2005
50,000       Manjil-Rudbar earthquake Iran          June 1990
45,000       İzmit earthquake         Turkey        August 1999
28,000       Khait earthquake         Tajikistan    July 1949
26,000       Bam earthquake           Iran          December 2003
```

The numbers here are only primary deaths - not secondary impact (such as the 12 million displaced/stranded by the Pakistan floods of 2010)

It would be in poor taste to express a judgement on the US, without first considering a much more significant and damning judgement on these countries with a Muslim majority.

Perhaps we should simply consider: natural disasters happen.

Comment: do you want to say anything that is well understood can not be from God? if so this is wrong. all the nature is a tool in control of God and understanding how nature works does not mean there is nothing controlling nature. it is like when one cut a fruit with a knife one say: the cutting process of knife is well understood. OK. but this does not mean that there is no mind controlling the hand and hand controlling the knife. the main question is why nature works? not how nature works. scientists are lost in jungle of "how" questions and have forgotten "why" questions. wider view is needed.

Comment: @Ahmadi take that far enough and you end up defining God === physics. But: I stated no opinion on tht, other than "this was not unexpected". As for reasons... You have to admit, anyone trying to argue "this was to punish the US" first needs to have a pretty good explanation of the rest of this answer.

Comment: @MarcGravell When I see those numbers I start thinking to this question has sense http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2847/do-the-military-have-the-technology-to-trigger-earthquakes

Comment: @adopilot that's just denial and paranoia